# hamcrest containsInAnyOrder only working for specific order

Tags: java, collections, junit, hamcrest

I'm trying to make a test that checks if an a certain list has items and I don't care about the order.
The way I want to be able to do this is by testing the item has a certain property with a certain value.

I've isolated the senario with the following code:

Class I'm using:

```java
public class A {
    private String propA;

    public A (final String propA) {
        this.propA = propA;
    }

    public String getPropA() {
        return propA;
    }

    public void setPropA(final String propA) {
        this.propA = propA;
    }
}
```

TestClass

```java
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue.hasProperty;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class HamcrestCollectionTest {
    @Test
    public void testContainsInAnyOrder() {
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();

        list.add(new A("a"));
        list.add(new A("b"));

        assertThat(list, containsInAnyOrder(hasProperty("propA", equalTo("b")), hasProperty("propA", equalTo("a"))));
    }
}
```

This test fails. If i switch around the values of the list inside the countainsInAnyOrder, then this works. This was not exactly what I was expecting from the "containsInAnyOrder".

What is the correct way to do this?
Or is there a way to check that the individual values are present?

Comment: I tried the same test and it works. Have you tried this with a minimal project? What version of Hamcrest are you using?

Comment: I have tried with these exact 2 classes, I don't see how i can get more minimal than this. The version of junit is 4.11 and the version of hamcrest is 1.3.

Comment: I just tried the exact same code on new project on my computer and indeed, it's working. I think I'll need to doublecheck the version of hamcrest on the project where it didn't work. I'll get back to you on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have discovered what the problem was. It was indeed a version of a hamcrest class that caused the problem.

Steps taken:

1. updated the version of the **maven-dependency-plugin**

   - reason:

     - Unable to run the command **mvn dependency:tree**.
     - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound
2. changed my mockito dependency from **mockito-all** to **mockito-core**

   - reason:

     - The **mockito-all** dependency contained a version of the class **org.hamcrest.Matcher** directly.
     - This is not simply visible when you look at what dependencie are loaded (since it's in the **mockito-all** jar itself and not in a dependency of the jar.
3. set the version of **hamcrest-core** to **1.3** in the dependencyManagement.

   - reason:

     - **mockito-core** has a dependency to **hamcrest-core** but uses version **1.1**
     - the **mockito-core** version of **hamcrest-core** got precedence over the **junit** version of the **hamcrest-core** dependency.

So basicaly it was a conflict caused by using **mockito-all**.